# What is the best way to store (possibly hundreds) of strings in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, string, plist, spreadsheet, storage

There is a possibility that a user of my app may enter tens/hundreds/thousands of pieces of information into the app. For example, they may enter names, addresses, phone numbers of various people.

What would you recommend is the best way to store (a potentially large amount) these strings?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to export the inputted data as a text delimited file or a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite3 is a great way to store a large amount of data.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Failing that you could always use NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 3):

You should consider either CoreData or sqlite.  CoreData can be over an xml or sqlite database.  If you use sqlite, you should consider the fmdb wrapper on github

But, a lot depends on the access patterns.  Sqlite is very fast but it also offers querying capabilities.